# SignalR client is not being connected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

Here's my hub class:

```
public class ZaaloverzichtHub : Hub
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ZaaloverzichtHub>();

    private static readonly Lazy<ZaaloverzichtHub> instance = new Lazy<ZaaloverzichtHub>(() => new ZaaloverzichtHub());

    public static ZaaloverzichtHub Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }



    public void Send()//PartialViewResult zaaloverzicht)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("test");
    }


}
```

And here's the javascript in my view:

```
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection.ZaaloverzichtHub;

    connection.client.broadcastMessage = function (zaaloverzicht) {
        window.alert(zaaloverzicht);
    }
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

I'm calling the Send() method from my controller

```
var hub = ZaaloverzichtHub.Instance;
hub.Send();
```

The Send() method in the hub is being called however nothing is happening on the client side. I know the client is not being connected to the hub because when i make a method like this:

```
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

And place a breakpoint, the breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: Well, I got it working. Turns out i was referencing an old jquery library which wasn't included in my project.

Answer (score 2):

The convention for SignalR is to use a lowercase naming scheme on the client side unless explicitly named using an attribute in c#

```
var connection = $.connection.zaaloverzichtHub;//note the case change on Z to z
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually knew about this convention, but for some reason missed that. However, this doesn't solve the problem.